# Hello, I'm trying to install channels but it's not installing because It is finding it hard to install twisted, what can I do?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm trying to install channels but it's not installing because It is finding it hard to install twisted, what can I do? it brings this error and stops. How can I go about this?

```
 copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\chain.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\not-a-certificate -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing1.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing2-duplicate.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing2.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\mail\test\rfc822.message -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\twisted\mail\test
    copying src\twisted\python\test\_deprecatetests.py.3only -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\twisted\python\test
    copying src\twisted\trial\test\_assertiontests.py.3only -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\twisted\trial\test
    copying src\twisted\words\im\instancemessenger.glade -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\twisted\words\im
    copying src\twisted\words\xish\xpathparser.g -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\twisted\words\xish
    running build_ext
    building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\sirto\Anaconda3\envs\feb2020\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sirto\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jb1hixq_\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sirto\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jb1hixq_\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\sirto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bqr18jdh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\sirto\Anaconda3\envs\feb2020\Include\twisted' Check the logs for full command output.`
```

Answer (score 2):

Install [visual studio build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) so that twisted can be compiled (as error states) or download and [install unofficial compiled wheel](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted)

You are looking for `Twisted‑20.3.0‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl` as you are using python 3.8 x64

Comment: Thanks for the response, i did try downloading but it's a very large file, also this site doesn't open, can you please help me confirm if the link is correct. Thanks